# Can the watch app receive background info even if the app is in the background?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos

I cannot figure out how to make `updateApplicationContext` data arrive on the watch before the watch app is foregrounded. It seems to work only when the watch app is foregrounded.

How can the watch receive files while in the background?

This is what I've been trying to accomplish:

iOS code:

```
func sendDataToWatch() {
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            do {
                try WCSession.default.updateApplicationContext(["key":value])
            } catch {
                print("ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Watch code:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext
        applicationContext:[String : Any]) {

      //handle data when it arrives

    }
```

I noticed that the WatchConnectivity was provided with a handler function. Is this something I should set up to be able to handle background connectivity while the Watch App is backgrounded or not even launched?

```
func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        // Use a switch statement to check the task type
        switch task {
        case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        default:
            // make sure to complete unhandled task types
            task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post an example.

Comment: I have edited the question with my example

Answer (score 1):

According to apple you can send data from iPhone to Apple Watch using SendMessage while session is reachable.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage

> Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active
>   and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background and
>   makes it reachable.

**You can use below methods to send data from the iPhone to Apple Watch**

Swift 2.2

```
let msg = ["IPrequest":"IsLogin"]

WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: { (replyDict) in
    print(replyDict)
    }, errorHandler: { (error) in
        print(error)
})
```

**Received dictionary using below method**

Swift 2.2

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

        print("Response:\(message)")

    }
}
```

I have implemented above solution in one of the my project.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I'd like to do it the other way around. From the iOS to Watch App. From the same documentation page: "Calling this method from your iOS app does not wake up the corresponding WatchKit extension."

Comment: I'm trying to think of an app that does what you are describing well. Many don't sync until opened.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to send data over to the watch while the iOS application is running. When a local notification scheduled from the iOS triggers, I want to show data that has already been sent to the watch before. If I try to send the data while the notification is begin processed it would take too long. I want to display an image in the notification but it will be generated by the iOS application via MKMapSnapshotter while the iOS app is running.